# R: extract address using getURL()

Tags: r, google-maps, url, geocoding, spatial

I have a ton of google map URL's and would like to obtain a clean address from the URL's for geocoding. I recently found getURL() in the RCurl package, which gets me a ton of information

> library(RCurl)
>
> getURL("https://maps.google.com/?q=loc%3A+%32%34%34%30+Seattle%2C+%39%38%31%31%36+WA+US")

but all I'm really interested in is getting the address snippet located towards the front end of the getURL() output:

> ...< meta content=\"loc: **2440 Seattle, 98116 WA US** - Google Maps\" property=\"og:title\">...

**Update**: I just realized the above URL address is a bad example, here's a different example:

> getURL("https://maps.google.com/?q=loc%3A+%31%30%30%35%36+Interlake+Ave+N+seattle+WA+US")
>
> ...< meta content=\"loc: **10056 Interlake Ave N seattle WA US** - Google Maps\" property=\"og:title\">...

Does anyone have suggestions on how to efficiently go about this? My appologies, I'm an intermediate with R and would appreciate your help. Thanks!!

Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Google Maps XML-API as follows:

```
require(XML)

burl <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="
address <- "2440 Seattle, 98116 WA US"
request <- paste0(burl,URLencode(address))

doc <- htmlTreeParse(request, useInternalNodes=TRUE)
# Interpreted Adress
xmlValue(doc[["//formatted_address"]])
[1] "2440, Seattle-Tacoma International Airport (SEA), Seattle, WA 98158, USA"
```

**EDIT**
If you only have the encoded URL use `URLdecode` to decode it instead of downloading the URL:

```
URL <- "https://maps.google.com/?q=loc%3A+%32%34%34%30+Seattle%2C+%39%38%31%31%36+WA+US"
URL <- gsub(".*loc","",URL) # Get rid of https://...
URL <- URLdecode(URL)
gsub("[:]|[+]", " ", URL) # Get rid of ":" and "+"
[1] "  2440 Seattle, 98116 WA US"
```

Comment: Thanks Floo0, but I don't have the addresses. I only have the URL's that go to Google Maps and was wondering how to extract each address from each URL. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Edited my Answer... Hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Or substitute the geocode url for the original `url = sub(".*q=loc", "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=", URL)` and retrieve the formatted address `htmlParse(url)[["string(//formatted_address)"]]`